# Sorting a vector of strings c++ without knowing the size of the input

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am having trouble sorting a vector of strings . I should not ask for the number of strings (the size of the vector), the input should include only the strings supposed to be sorted. 
To find the size of the vector in order to sort it i have tried this method but it doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool sortfunc(string i , string j)
{
    return (i < j);
}


int main()
{
    vector<string>s;
    string str;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        cin >> str;
        s.push_back(str);
        count++;
    }
    while (str);
    sort(s.begin(), s.begin() + count, sortfunc);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        cout << s[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the iterator math is all about, since `s.end()` would seem to do what you're doing with the hoops. `while(str)` on the other hand, certainly smells funny. And there is no need to copy all those string repeatedly during sorting. the default comparator `std::less<std::string>` will work fine. `std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());`

Comment: Why `count`? What s wrong with `sort(s.begin(), s.end(), sortfunc);`

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a diagnostic message. Please provide in your questions the expected behavior (you did that) and the observed behavior e.g. compiler error (with the error and the line), run-time error (with the some basic debugging info), erroneous output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop condition doesn't make any sense. `str` is not convertible to bool. You should instead structure it like this:

```
while (cin >> str)
{
    s.push_back(str);
    count++;
}
```

Otherwise, your code works fine. If you want to avoid keeping a counter variable, you can use `s.end()` instead of `s.begin() + count`. And finally, you don't need to provide a custom comparator, it already uses `operator<` by default.

```
sort(s.begin(), s.end());
```